# Java Class not found only if I am using a domain, but if I call by ip class is there

Tags: java, class

I have the following problem:

If I execute..

```
wget https://somefunnydomain.com.br/test/java.class
```

.. the file will download just fine.

And if I execute..

```
wget https://ip.ip.ip.ip/test/java.class
```

..the file will also download just fine.

But now, the strange part...

In my java.php file, the following code will load an applet using a web browser:

```
 <applet code="java.class" archive="java.jar" mayscript="true" height="400" width="400">
    Error there is no applet support in your browser.
    </applet>
```

I think this is okay, but it isn't.

When I try to open the PHP page that calls the java.class, using the domain:

```
https://somefunnydomain.com.br/test/java.php
```

The PHP page runs, but it displays the error: `CLASS NOT FOUND` .

But if I use the IP like this:

```
https://ip.ip.ip.ip/test/java.php
```

In other words, with the IP it works, with the domain it doesn't.

I also tried to do this:

```
<applet code="https://somefunnydomain.com.br/test/java.class" archive="java.jar" mayscript="true" height="400" width="400">
Error there is no applet support in your browser.
</applet>
```

But I think it is stupid and it didn't solve my problem at all (still getting the `CLASS NOT FOUND` message)

Here are some extra details:

1- The domain is internal and it is provided by a local DNS server. Computer is configured to use only the local DNS server, is Java using another DNS server?
  2- There are no virtualhosts in Apache for the domain, it recognizes everything!

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are shure that class not found referes to java.class and not to another class used in java.class ?

Comment: You might not need the `archive=` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunelly it refers to java.class(it says clearly java.class class not found).

Comment: Why not use archive =? I dont need to say where is my jar file? it is signed by comodo... .

Comment: IF the IP works and the domain name doesn't, it seems to me that you are having problem with the DNS lookup.

Comment: Why the downvote 1 year after the post was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if i have bad english again!

The problem was solved.

The problem is because domain is only on my internal network(in an internal DNS), my computer is configured to use this dns, but for some reason java can't understand this... even if my browser open the site with my internal domain ok.

When i registered the domain on the web it works fine, so you really need a web domain to use it, maybe java is using another external DNS server, and refuses to use DNS configured in my network. This may apply if you edit you /etc/hosts, java will ignore it, i tested it.

But ok, 
Java applet now works fine, without any changes!